# Extend checkbox control on C#.net

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

I want to extend checkbox control which can use on every form.

If check box is checked than it will return "Y" otherwise "N".

How may i extend check box control and use it in other forms ?

Comment: Why not just use the `Checkbox.Checked` property?

Comment: I have char string one in my database for the specific fields. So i have to store "Y" or "N". So all the time i have to check if checkbox is checked than store "Y" otherwise "N". I want to create a property or control which return "Y" or "N" on the basis of check box is checked or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extension method is quick and easy, but you can't do that in .NET 2.0, as you mentioned in your tags.

You would have to create a new user control, and place a `CheckBox` on it.
You would then have to respond to the most common things to make it act like a `CheckBox`.
For example, you would have to handle your control's `Resize()` event, and apply whatever change made accordingly to the `CheckBox` within.
After all that is done, you now have a fully-functional `CheckBox` control of your own creation that very much mimics that of the original one.

Only then you can create a public get property like so:

```
public bool CheckedText
{
     get
     {
         return (CheckBox1.Checked ? "Y" : "N");
     }
}
```

And that is it.
But if I were you, I wouldn't go through all that hassle.
I would just do that check myself right before I write to the database.
Extending an existing user control for such a minute feature is not worth it, honestly.

Comment: @krunal shah; I should have mentioned this: This solution I just gave you lets you drag-and-drop, size, and align the `CheckBox` control in design time, which I assumed what you wanted to do.  You can avoid having to rewrite all the common UI events like I said and simply create a class that inherits from `CheckBox` with the added public get property, but that would mean you can't really see it or lay it out in design time; you would have to dynamically create at design time, and place it the correct coordinates, which is not convenient most of the time.